# Convert MKV with DTS audio to MKV with AAC, AC3 or MP3 audio

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, ffmpeg, conversion

I have an MKV with multi-channel DTS audio. Using ffmpeg from the command line I want to convert to MKV with either multi-channel AAC, AC3 or MP3 audio. Can someone please tell me command-line for all three? Also if I want to downmix any of the 3 formats to stereo then what do I need to add? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't believe FFmpeg supports MP3 Surround, so for AAC and AC3, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a aac output.mkv

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a ac3 output.mkv
```

To downmix to stereo, insert `-ac 2` i.e. for stereo MP3

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 output.mkv
```

you can insert `-b:a N` to specify audio bitrate where N is in bits i.e.  `128000` or `128k`